# How come the field value on the related object isn't updated after saving?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I have a one-to-many relationship in django. (one Author is to many Books)
The problem is that when I update a field of an Author through a Book, I get the old value for the Author's field when retrieving the Book again.

```
>>> book1 = Book.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> book1.author.email
u'Old Author'
>>> book1.author.pk
1
>>> book1.author.email = "New Author"
>>> book1.author.save()
>>> book1.author.email
u'New Author'
>>> author1 = Author.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> author1.email
u'New Author'
>>> book2 = Book.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> book2.author.pk
1
>>> book2.author.email
u'Old Author'    # I'm expecting this to be u'New Author'
```

What am I missing here?

---

This is an old project using Django 1.5.5

**EDIT**: I was actually editing an EmailField to which I was entering a non-valid e-mail. However, shouldn't it have failed in the first place rather than result in this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Is this your actual code? I can't see why it would give that result. Can you show the models?

Comment: What about `book2.author.refresh_from_db()` ?

Comment: @Krystofee unfortunately, I'm using an older version of django which doesn't have refresh_from_db.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I changed some field names and I think I figured it out. I was updating an EmailField.